# Laravel blade creating url

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple problem, basically I am getting name of the website from database and create a link according to it's name. it looks like:

```
@foreach ($websites as $website)
    <a class="websites" href=" {{  asset ($website->name )}}"> {{ asset ($website->name )}}
    </a> 
@endforeach
```

Which gives for example: `http://localhost/name`

Howver links needs to be like this:

`http://localhost/website/name` how can I add `/website` into my URL using blade template in laravel?

Comment: Did you define a route for this url you want to create?

Comment: Yes I did:     Route::get('/website/{name}', 'BuilderController@website');

Comment: use base_url().'website'.$website->name or  url('website/'.$website->name )

Comment: I just want to add that `a class="websites" href="/name">` works fine too (but it's not using blade)

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
{{ url('website/' . $website->name) }}
```

Comment: perfect :) thank you! I will accept this answer in 9 minutes :P

Comment: @Przemek Just a friendly reminder to accept answer which you found helpful.

Comment: @Przemek You said you would accept this answer in 9 mins and in 12 days it will be 3 years.

Comment: Let it go guys, its almost 5 years. Accept your fate.

Answer (score 5):

This have some improvement on @Laran answer regarding best practices.

You would better use url parameters instead of concatenating the $name parameter

`{{ url('website', [$name]) }}`

And using named routes will be better to decouple the routing from the views.

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('website')->name('website');
```

and write inside your `{{ route('website', [$name]) }}`

Comment: This `{{ url('website', $name) }}` also seems to work without the square braces